# eBay API java.lang.ClassCastException: GetSuggestedCategoriesResponseType incompatible with GeteBayDetailsResponseType

Tags: vb.net, ebay-api

I am trying to run a call to the `GetSuggestedCategories` API call on a button press. This works fine.

Next, I am trying to make a call to the `GeteBayDetails` API call on a subsequent button press. This is where I get the following error:

```
{"java.lang.ClassCastException:  com.ebay.domain.apisoap.pres.service.hosting.soap.basecomponents.GetSuggestedCategoriesResponseType incompatible with com.ebay.domain.apisoap.pres.service.hosting.soap.basecomponents.GeteBayDetailsResponseType"}
```

What is befuddling me is that whatever method I call first I can continue to call without error. I simply cannot make a call to the next method without getting errors.

Each method contains its `appID`, `devID`, `certID`, `authToken`, `endpoint`, `callname`, `serviceRequest`, etc, so have had difficulty identifying why calling the `GeteBayDetails` request is saying it is incompatible with a reference to the `GetRequestedCategories` call when I have made no reference to it.

Here is my method call for `GetSuggestedCategories`:

```
Public Function GetSuggestedCategories(keywords As String, PostingStore As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    appId = "My ID"
    devId = "My ID"
    certId = "My ID"
    store1Auth = "My ID"
    store2Auth = "My ID"
    endpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/wsapi"

    Dim returnCategories As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim callName As String = "GetSuggestedCategories"
    Dim siteId As String = SiteCodeType.US
    Dim version As String = "1031"

    'build the request URL
    Dim requestURL As String = endpoint +
        "?callname=" + callName +
        "&siteid=" + siteId +
        "&appid=" + appId +
        "&version=" + version +
        "&routing=default"

    'Create the service
    Dim service As eBayAPIInterfaceClient = New eBayAPIInterfaceClient("eBayAPI", requestURL)
    Dim requesterCredentials As CustomSecurityHeaderType = New CustomSecurityHeaderType
    requesterCredentials.eBayAuthToken = If(PostingStore = "Store 1", store1Auth, If(PostingStore = "Store 2", store2Auth, Nothing))
    If requesterCredentials.eBayAuthToken = Nothing Then
        service.Close()
        service = Nothing
        requesterCredentials = Nothing
        returnCategories.Add("3", "Amazon Auth Token Not Recognized or Store not set up.")
        Return returnCategories
    End If
    requesterCredentials.Credentials = New UserIdPasswordType
    requesterCredentials.Credentials.AppId = appId
    requesterCredentials.Credentials.DevId = devId
    requesterCredentials.Credentials.AuthCert = certId

    'Make the call to AddFixedPriceItem
    Dim request As eBayWSDL.GetSuggestedCategoriesRequestType = New GetSuggestedCategoriesRequestType
    request.Version = version
    request.Query = keywords

    Dim asyncResponse As GetSuggestedCategoriesResponse
    Try
        'asyncResponse = Await service.GetSuggestedCategoriesAsync(requesterCredentials, request)
        'Dim response As GetSuggestedCategoriesResponseType = asyncResponse.GetSuggestedCategoriesResponse1
        Dim response As GetSuggestedCategoriesResponseType = service.GetSuggestedCategories(requesterCredentials, request)
        If response.Ack <> AckCodeType.Failure Then
            If Not response.SuggestedCategoryArray Is Nothing Then
                returnCategories.Add("0", "Complete with no errors.")
                For Each cID In response.SuggestedCategoryArray.SuggestedCategory
                    returnCategories.Add(cID.Category.CategoryName, cID.Category.CategoryID)
                Next
            ElseIf Not response.Any Is Nothing Then
                returnCategories.Add("0", "Complete with no errors.")
                For Each xmlResponse In response.Any
                    Dim xmlConverter As New XmlDocumentConverter(xmlResponse)
                    Dim allCategories As Dictionary(Of String, String) = xmlConverter.ConvertToStringDictionary("CategoryID", "CategoryName", "Category")
                    For Each cat In allCategories
                        returnCategories.Add(cat.Key, cat.Value)
                    Next

                Next
            Else
                returnCategories.Add("2", "No Suggested Categories Were Found.")
            End If
        Else
            returnCategories.Add("1", "Errors returned.")
            Dim err As ErrorType
            For Each err In response.Errors
                returnCategories.Add(err.ErrorCode, err.ShortMessage)
            Next err

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        service.Close()
        service = Nothing
        requesterCredentials = Nothing
        request = Nothing
        asyncResponse = Nothing
    End Try
    Return returnCategories
```

And here is my method to call `GeteBayDetails`:

```
Public Function GetShippingServiceDetails(PostingStore As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    appId = "My ID"
    devId = "My ID"
    certId = "My ID"
    store1Auth = "My ID"
    store2Auth = "My ID"
    endpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/wsapi"

    Dim returnExcludes As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim callName As String = "GeteBayDetails"
    Dim siteId As String = SiteCodeType.US
    Dim version As String = "1031"

    'build the request URL
    Dim requestURL As String = endpoint +
        "?callname=" + callName +
        "&siteid=" + siteId +
        "&appid=" + appId +
        "&version=" + version +
        "&routing=default"

    'Create the service
    Dim service As eBayAPIInterfaceClient = New eBayAPIInterfaceClient("eBayAPI", requestURL)
    Dim requesterCredentials As CustomSecurityHeaderType = New CustomSecurityHeaderType

    Try
        requesterCredentials.eBayAuthToken = If(PostingStore = "Store 1", store1Auth, If(PostingStore = "Store 2", store2Auth, Nothing))
        If requesterCredentials.eBayAuthToken Is Nothing Then
            Throw New NullReferenceException("An auth token was not found for the selected store")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        service.Close()
        service = Nothing
        requesterCredentials = Nothing
        returnExcludes.Add("3", ex.Message)
        Return returnExcludes
    End Try

    requesterCredentials.Credentials = New UserIdPasswordType
    requesterCredentials.Credentials.AppId = appId
    requesterCredentials.Credentials.DevId = devId
    requesterCredentials.Credentials.AuthCert = certId

    'Make the call to AddFixedPriceItem
    Dim request As eBayWSDL.GeteBayDetailsRequestType = New GeteBayDetailsRequestType
    request.Version = version
    Dim detailNameList As New List(Of DetailNameCodeType)
    detailNameList.Add(DetailNameCodeType.ShippingServiceDetails)
    request.DetailName = detailNameList.ToArray

    'Dim asyncResponse As GeteBayDetailsResponse
    Try
        'asyncResponse = Await service.GeteBayDetailsAsync(requesterCredentials, request)
        'Dim response As GeteBayDetailsResponseType = asyncResponse.GeteBayDetailsResponse1
        Dim response As GeteBayDetailsResponseType = service.GeteBayDetails(requesterCredentials, request)
        If response.Ack <> AckCodeType.Failure Then
            If Not response.ExcludeShippingLocationDetails Is Nothing Then
                returnExcludes.Add("0", "Complete with no errors.")
                For Each cID In response.ShippingServiceDetails
                    If cID.ValidForSellingFlow = True Then
                        returnExcludes.Add(cID.ServiceType.ToString, cID.Description)
                    End If
                Next
            ElseIf Not response.Any Is Nothing Then
                returnExcludes.Add("0", "Complete with no errors.")
                For Each xmlResponse In response.Any
                    Dim xmlConverter As New XmlDocumentConverter(xmlResponse)
                    Dim allCategories As Dictionary(Of String, String) = xmlConverter.ConvertToStringDictionary("ServiceType", "Description", "False", "")
                    For Each cat In allCategories
                        returnExcludes.Add(cat.Key, cat.Value)
                    Next

                Next
            Else
                returnExcludes.Add("2", "No Suggested Locations Were Found.")
            End If
        Else
            returnExcludes.Add("1", "Errors returned.")
            Dim err As ErrorType
            For Each err In response.Errors
                returnExcludes.Add(err.ErrorCode, err.ShortMessage)
            Next err

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        service.Close()
        service = Nothing
        requesterCredentials = Nothing
        request = Nothing
        'asyncResponse = Nothing
    End Try
    Return returnExcludes
End Function
```

Comment: Is the response object disposable too? If so try closing it in your finally blocks.

Comment: Good thought. I actually tried that as well, but to no effect, as it could not be closed, only set to nothing. You can see the commented code in the finally block that represents my attempt at setting it to nothing.

Interestingly, I have found a solution that involves changing my HTML bindings in app.config. My only issue now is that I have a working product that I do not understand what fixed it. I will post an answer with my code later tonight in hopes of seeing if anyone can point me to what solved the issue.